# Are there examples of human genes using meiotic drive?

Tags: genetics

Meiotic drive is a type of intragenomic conflict, whereby one or more loci within a genome will affect a manipulation of the meiotic process in such a way as to favor the transmission of one or more alleles over another, regardless of its phenotypic expression. More simply, meiotic drive is when one copy of a gene is passed on to offspring more than the expected 50% of the time.

But do humans have such genes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! [Jeffrey and Neumann 2002](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v31/n3/abs/ng910.html) report evidence of meiotic drive at a recombination hot spot in the [MHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_histocompatibility_complex).

Note that [mtDNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA) could arguably be considered as an extreme case of sex-dependent meiotic drive. Mothers transmit mtDNA at rate of almost 1, while fathers transmit mtDNA at a rate of almost 0.